# I got error in build apk in android studio of React-Native

Tags: react-native

E:\React Native\Projects\ghar-par-hospital-rn-app\android\app\build\intermediates\external_file_lib_dex_archives\release\out

Comment: Is the error unable to delete?

Comment: Please provide full error log.